# Can a Microsoft Teams Calendar be pulled into Outlook integrated multiple Calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

In Microsoft Teams, one can add a Calendar tab to a Microsoft Teams channel.

Can these be pulled into Microsoft Outlook in a way that overlays all of the calendars, including your personal and other people's calendars displayed on one calendar?

Comment: Is my reply helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Overlay calendar steps: choose calendars and right click then choose overlay. All calendar will be shown in one calendar.

[image]

For more details: [View multiple calendars at the same time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-multiple-calendars-at-the-same-time-fffa8783-0556-4ea1-ba62-3ed8a95a903c)

Comment: I'm wondering between Teams and Outlook how you tell if a calendar is the same calendar.  How are they uniquely identified?